# preprocessing (center and scale) only specific variables (numeric variables)

Tags: r, dplyr, logistic-regression, r-caret, training-data

I have a dataframe that consist of numerical and non-numerical variables. I am trying to fit a logisic regression model predicting my variable "risk" based on all other variables, optimizing AUC using a 6-fold cross validation.
However, I want to  center and scale all numerical explanatory variables. My code raises no errors or warning but somehow I fail to figure out how to tell `train()` through `preProcess` (or in some other way) to just center and scale my numerical variables.

Here is the code:

```
test <- train(risk ~ .,
              method = "glm",
              data = df,
              family = binomial(link = "logit"),
              preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
              trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                       number = 6,
                                       classProbs = TRUE,
                                       summaryFunction = prSummary),
              metric = "AUC")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to preprocess all numerical variables in original df first and then applying `train` function over scaled df

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

df <- df %>%
        dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)

test <- train(risk ~ .,
              method = "glm",
              data = df,
              family = binomial(link = "logit"),
              trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                       number = 6,
                                       classProbs = TRUE,
                                       summaryFunction = prSummary),
              metric = "AUC")
```

Comment: Does scale do the same as preProcess? Also, I assume preProcess can be excluded in this case?

Comment: @jxpython, yes, scale function centers numerical cols to have mean zero and variance one as an standardized normal distribution

Comment: can you explain why mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ scale) does not work and mutate_if(is.numeric, scale) does? Notice ~ in the function.

Comment: This will cause data leakage, and thus optimistic bias during resampling since you are using information from the out of fold resamples. The correct way would be to apply all preprocessing steps during resampling using info only data the respective train sets. To scale only some numeric variables during resampling your best options are [`recipes`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recipes/index.html) or [mlr3](https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/). `preProcess` inside of train does preprocessing correctly using only respective train sets data but I think you can not specify only certain variables.

Comment: But if you want to preprocess all numerical variables using `c("center", "scale")` then you can use `preProcess` inside of train since it will do just that. It will not touch categorical variables. See [?preProcess](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/preProcess):   Non-numeric data will not be pre-processed and their values will be in the data frame produced by the predict function. This applies to calling `preProcess` within train too.